# Stop status bar from rotating when switching views on orientation

Tags: ios, statusbar, screen-rotation

I have 2 views. A portrait detail view that when rotated to landscape, does a manual segue to a full screen photo viewer. The portrait detail view returns NO for shouldAutorotate and prefersStatusBarHidden.

When I rotate from portrait to landscape, just before the landscape view fades in, I can see the portrait view resize slightly as the status bar gets hidden and then the status bar moves from the top to the side.

The transition looks a bit ugly. I'd rather the status bar remains visible as the device is rotated to portrait, since it will get covered over by the landscape view anyway. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
The only way I see it working is if you do the rotation yourself and not with the device ability

Comment: Thanks Gal, I think you're right. If I only allow Portrait orientation in the Info.plist supported interface orientations, then as expected the status bar doesn't rotate. But then the "landscape" photo view would have to be created with a 90 degree rotation on all the subviews AND the whole view would need to turn around 180 degrees when rotated to the other landscape. So basically I don't think it is worth the effort for something that most people won't notice!